# Muliplying Elements of a Vector one more each time

Tags: r

I am trying to create a vector from another vector where I multiply the numbers in the vector one more each time.

For example if I had (1,2,3) the new vector would be (1, 1 x 2, 1 x 2 x 3)=(1,2,6)

I tried to create a loop for this as seen below. It seems to work for whole numbers but not decimals. I am not sure why.

```
x <- c(0.99,0.98,0.97,0.96,0.95)
for(i in 1:5){x[i]=prod(x[1:i])}
```

The result given is  0.9900000 0.9702000 0.9316831 0.8590845 0.7303385

which is incorrect as `prod(x)` =  0.8582777. Which is not the same as the last element of the vector.

Does anyone know why this is the case? Or have a suggestion for improvement in my code to get the correct answer.

Comment: For completeness, a for-loop: `out <- numeric(length(x)); for(i in seq_len(length(x))){ out[i] <- prod(x[1:i]) }; out` The problem with your solution is that you update `x` while I created a new object.

Answer (score 4):

```
test<-c(1,2,3)
cumprod(test)
[1] 1 2 6
```

As @akrun suggests, one can achieve the same with:

```
Reduce("*", test, accumulate = TRUE)
```